# What are the differences between `Map.clear()` vs `new Map()` in Javascript?

Tags: mobx-react

Recently came across an issue with `mobx` where an `observable.map` does not react when modified its state with ES6 `Map.prototype.clear()`. However, when it's reassigned with `new Map()` it seems to work as expected. What could be the differences using those in Javascript?

Comment: Can you provide more detail on how you're using this within your code?

Answer (score 0):

Map.prototype.clear does not yield a new map instance, but rather it modifies the existing object instance.  new Map(), on the other hand, creates a completely new instance (obviously), and is thus better for functional programming (treating objects as immutable) even those it can be a bit less efficient in some cases.